# PostgREST - How to create tables?

Tags: postgrest

I want to create a new table using postgREST, but I was not able to find anything about this in the documentation. Is it possible to create tables? If yes, how?

Sorry if this questions was already asked, but unfortunately I always found solutions for **postgres** (without **t** :D)

Thx :)

Comment: PostgREST is just a REST API for a PostgreSQL (or just Postgres) database and does not contain any tables. Any table you want to use, needs to be created in the database your postgREST installation connects to using a [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) statement

Comment: Thx for the answer. My question is: is there any REST call possible to create a table in my postgresql? I want to write a little controller which will create a table for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create stored function that creates the table for you, then call that function via postgrest

something like:

```
create or replace function create_foo_table() returns void as 
$$
begin

  execute format('create table foo (id int primary key)')

end 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

then call `/rpc/create_foo_table` in Postgrest

you'd need to reload Postgrest's schema cache after this, in order to read the table: https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/admin.html?highlight=reload#schema-reloading

This likely has security implications, so be careful, especially if using dynamic SQL to create the table